# Remove Stop Words/ Connecting Words From Text File

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, stop-words

I'm working on a program that reads a text file and displays the top 10 most frequent words in ascending order and prints them. I've defined the stop words/ connecting words and written the code to remove them from the frequent words analysis, however, the stop words are still including within the analysis.

```
% Prints the words
print_top_words(File, N):-
    read_file_to_string(File, String, [encoding(utf8)]),
    re_split("\\w+", String, Words),
    lower_case(Words, Lower),
    sort(1, @=<, Lower, Sorted),
    exclude(word_to_ignore, Sorted, RelevantWords),
    merge_words(RelevantWords, Counted),
    sort(2, @>, Counted, Top_words),
    writef("Top %w words:\nRank\tCount\tWord\n", [N]),
    print_top_words(Top_words, N, 1).

% Predicate to filter out words that are to be ignored.
word_to_ignore(Word) :-
    ignore_words(IgnoreWords),
    member(Word, IgnoreWords).

% Defines the words to ignore.
ignore_words(['', 'a', 'an', 'the', 'for', 'of', 'and', 'to', 'in', 'is', 'it', 'on', 'that', 'with', 'this', 'you', 'be', 'are', 'at', 'or', 'as', 'if', 'not', 'from']).

lower_case([_], []):-!.
lower_case([_, Word|Words], [Lower - 1|Rest]):-
    string_lower(Word, Lower),
    lower_case(Words, Rest).

merge_words([], []):-!.
merge_words([Word - C1, Word - C2|Words], Result):-
    !,
    C is C1 + C2,
    merge_words([Word - C|Words], Result).
merge_words([W|Words], [W|Rest]):-
    merge_words(Words, Rest).

print_top_words([], _, _):-!.
print_top_words(_, 0, _):-!.
print_top_words([Word - Count|Rest], N, R):-
    writef("%w\t%w\t%w\n", [R, Count, Word]),
    N1 is N - 1,
    R1 is R + 1,
    print_top_words(Rest, N1, R1).

main:-
    print_top_words("SuspiciousEmail.txt", 10).
```

Comment: `ignore_words(['', 'a', 'an', ...` with single quotes these aren't strings, they are quoted atoms. Member will not find `member('an', ["a", "an"])` but it will find `member("an", ["a", "an"])` so try changing the ignore words to have all double quotes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. So I updated it to having double quotes, however, unfortunately the words to ignore are still displaying within the frequency word count.

Comment: OK. on to `lower_case(["Cat","Dog","Cow"], Lower)` and it outputs words paired with numbers (and misses some words), so it results in `"Dog"-1` as an item, which is also written as `-("Dog", 1)`  and that pair won't be found in the list of exclude words which don't have numbers. You need to do the exclude exclude before adding counting numbers, or do it some other way.

Comment: Thank you very much, please may I have some guidance on this because I'm very new to prolog.